# Why I am not in the current window miners even with adequate hash rate?

Tags: mining, mining-pools

Currently, I am mining on the [Mini P2Pool](https://p2pool.io/mini/#pool) with around 7 KH/s hash rate. I got several payouts in the previous month, but I recently noticed the [Current Window Miners](https://mini.p2pool.observer/miners) page where those miners were listed who would get paid when a new block was found.

Now, I can't find my wallet address even if I have bigger hash rate than the last miner (3.2 KH/s).

How can miners enter into the current window? And how the "Pool share %" was calculated?